# HttpClient causing captcha while same page in browser doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, http

I wrote a little tool to check the availability of a product (yes, the PS5) by checking the products shop page:

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_sony-playstation®5-2661938.html");

   HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

   using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
   {
       var output = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
       Console.WriteLine(output.Result);
   }
```

For some reason the result page is requesting me to do a captcha while calling the exact same URL in my browser giving me the correct page without captcha.

What is the reason of this behaviour and how do I avoid it?

Comment: The reason of the behaviour is to avoid bot automation tools, like you've created, from doing things like you're attempting to do. Within your browser, you'll have cookies set and other browser state that helps identify you're a human - more and more sites are adding client side detection logic to understand interactions (think cursor movements, how long you take to read/click things etc)  to avoid bots, which can cause big surges of requests and other undesirable behaviour (i.e. impacting customer proposition, bots buying stock). Basically, it's there to try and stop you doing this!

Comment: Professionalised armies of bots buying up stocks of desirable items the moment they go on sale has become a massive problem for retailers. The good ones will be doing their best to prevent this happening and make space for genuine customers. Maybe you're only doing this for your own personal benefit and not to sell them on (or maybe not) but the site can't tell the difference between your request and one from a big-time bot, so it's trying to stop requests which appear to be from non-human users. If it's done well you won't be able to fool it without some fairly sophisticated impersonation.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I want to notify myself with an email if the product is in stock again, writing a bot oslt is not my intention (want to buy one for my wife for christmas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer but a workaround

This website is protected by Cloudflare, which shows you recaptcha that only solvable in javascript environment. Obviously, HttpClient does not have such. While there are some solutions for this in other languages, I could not find any for C#. Will show an example in Selenium, web testing framework, that uses web browser driver (in my case Chrome).

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
        {
            driver.Url = "https://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_sony-playstation®5-2661938.html";

            // selenium does not behave well when element you are looking for is not visible, 
            // this method helps us to close cookie banner that blocks the view
            CloseCookieBannerIfAppears(driver);

            var buyButton = By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, \"Badge\")]").FindElement(driver);

            Console.WriteLine(buyButton.Text); // Ausverkauft
        }

    } 

    private static void CloseCookieBannerIfAppears(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        var buttonInAcceptCookieBannerSelector = By.XPath("//button[@id=\"privacy-layer-accept-all-button\"]");
        var waitForCookieBanner = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        if (waitForCookieBanner.Until(x => x.FindElements(buttonInAcceptCookieBannerSelector).Count > 0))
        {
            driver.FindElement(buttonInAcceptCookieBannerSelector)
                 .Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Also looks like they have unprotected API, so you should be able to get this data directly as well. You can see that there is id parameter both in your link and in api call -  `_sony-playstation®5-2661938.html` vs `productId=2661938`

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://delivery-prod-teasermanagement.cloud.mmst.eu/api/teaser/find?productId=2661938");
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var status = JArray.Parse(content)[0]["promotionData"]["badge"];

        Console.WriteLine(status); // Ausverkauft
    }
}
```

Maybe there are some other edge cases, but you should be able to get the point.